# Delete tag sqlsql-server-2012

Tags: discussion

I hope I'm proposing this in the correct way.

[sqlsql-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlsql-server-2012) seems to be a spelling mistake of [sql-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012).

There were 2 questions with this tag, for which edits to change the tag from [sqlsql-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlsql-server-2012) to [sql-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) were both accepted.

Please delete [sqlsql-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlsql-server-2012).

Comment: Won't this tag delete itself after a short period of time if no new questions appear with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there are no questions associated with the tag, then it will be deleted automatically during the nightly cleanup script.

There is no need to actually do anything to delete the tag.

Reference: [Meta Stack Overflow: How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.

Comment: I thought so, but couldn't find the conversation.

Comment: Great, then my cleanup was useful!